# how to use Easy Docs theme to write a book?

Tags: themes

I installed this theme
http://shakenandstirredweb.com/theme/easy-docs

but I don't understand how it works: after install I have only page menu, post menu has disappeared. Page only appears as menu not as content. So how does it work ?

Answer (score 2):

not sure if you watched the [video on their site](http://shakenandstirredweb.com/theme/easy-docs), because that seems pretty self-explanatory (especially from 1:18 onwards) It also says clearly on the site that it is a one page and very basic theme:

> a page for documentation with a simple way to navigate between sections, and a basic page template for simple pages like a Changelog

So if you are looking for how to add Posts that are not "Sections", then you have perhaps downloaded the wrong theme?